# SQL STUFF function roll up multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I am trying to combine a field when entries are made on the same day. The user may enter a message multiple times for a given Source on the same day. The resulting table is following -

[image]

What I would like to do is make one entry combining the `MessageText` for `SourceID` on the same day.

I have it where it will create an record for the `SourceID` and the same day however it will place every `MessageText` for that `SourceID` no matter what the date is. It does give one row for the same days. For instance the `SourceID` has 2 entries on 2012-11-08 on 1 on 2017-07-11. It creates a row for 2012-11-08 and one for 2017-07-11 however it places all 3 `MessageText` in the row.

[image]

My code is -

```
SELECT distinct  s.SourceID, stuff ( (select ', ' + rtrim(x.MessageText)
                                            from [AVData].[dbo].[LogCentralMessageData] x
                                            inner join AVData.[dbo].[Source] a on a.SourceID = t.SourceID
                                            inner join(select distinct max(m.CreatedOn)over (partition by r.SourceSiteID, Convert(date, m.CreatedOn)) as maxDate, r.SourceSiteID
                                                from [AVData].[dbo].[LogCentralMessageData] m 
                                                left join AVData.[dbo].[Source] r on r.SourceID = m.SourceID
                                                )  t on t.SourceSiteID = a.SourceSiteID and convert(date, t.maxDate) = Convert(date, x.CreatedOn)

                                            where x.SourceID = a.SourceID  

                                            for XML path('')), 1, 1, '') message_text
        ,convert(date, t.CreatedOn) as CreatedDate


from [AVData].[dbo].[LogCentralMessageData] t

left join AVData.[dbo].[Source] s on s.SourceID = t.SourceID
order by SourceID, CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick...

```
SELECT 
    st1.SourceID,
    CAST(st1.CreatedOn AS DATE)
    message_text = STUFF(
                (SELECT 
                    CONCAT(', ', st2.MessageText)
                FROM 
                    dbo.SomeTable st2
                WHERE 
                    st1.SourceID = st2.SourceID
                    AND CAST(st1.CreatedOn AS DATE) = CAST(st2.CreatedOn AS DATE)
                ORDER BY 
                    st2.CtreatedOn
                FOR XML PATH ('')
                ), 1, 2, '')
FROM 
    dbo.SomeTable st1
GROUP BY 
    st1.SourceID,
    CAST(st1.CreatedOn AS DATE);
```

Comment: For some reason it does not recognize with anything prefixed with `st1.` and then I get - Incorrect syntax near the key word FOR

Comment: it was missing a "," after the `CAST` statement. When I put that in place the statement worked. Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

While using `stuff()` one thing to remember that this takes four arguments `stuff(Query for xml path(''),1,1,'')`.You can use stuff() like that -

```
stuff((select +'/'+(CASE WHEN t2.Name IS NOT NULL THEN t2.Name ELSE (ISNULL(t2.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(t2.LastName,'')) END)
                  from table2 t2 inner join table1 MR on t2.id = mr.id
                  where t2.ContactId = m2.contactid for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SourceID, cast(CreatedOn as date) as CreatedDate,  message_text = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + MessageText 
              FROM yourtable t1
              WHERE t1.id = t2.id
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') from yourtable t2
group by SourceID, cast(CreatedOn as date);
```

Comment: I received the same result as I did before.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT SourceID, cast(CreatedOn as date) as CreatedDate,  message_text =
STRING_AGG(st1.MessageText, ',')  -- <<<
FROM 
    dbo.SomeTable st1
GROUP BY 
    st1.SourceID,
    CAST(st1.CreatedOn AS DATE);
```